# itemView.getContext() in recyclerviewer forcing app to close when finish activity

Tags: android

I currently working with my project and have some trouble in my `RecyclerViewer` java class file, every time i put this code `((Activity)itemView.getContext()).finish();` when the complete button clicked it forced the app to close. how can solve this? that when i click the button complete it will finish the activity then reload the activity.

here is my code:

```
package com.example.asus.hatidtubigandriversapp.adapter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.asus.hatidtubigandriversapp.DeliveryListActivity;
import com.example.asus.hatidtubigandriversapp.R;
import com.example.asus.hatidtubigandriversapp.http.HttpHelper;
import com.example.asus.hatidtubigandriversapp.http.UrlList;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DeliveryListHelper extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DeliveryListHelper.ViewHolder> {
    private List<Integer> id = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> customer = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> qty = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> type = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> address = new ArrayList<>();

    public DeliveryListHelper(List<Integer> id, List<String> customer, List<String> qty, List<String> type, List<String> address) {
        this.id = id;
        this.customer = customer;
        this.qty = qty;
        this.type = type;
        this.address = address;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View getView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_list_delivery, viewGroup, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(getView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        viewHolder.itemId = this.id.get(i);
        viewHolder.tCustomer.setText(this.customer.get(i));
        viewHolder.tOrderQty.setText(this.qty.get(i));
        viewHolder.tWaterType.setText(this.type.get(i));
        viewHolder.tAddress.setText(this.address.get(i));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.id.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        int itemId = 0;
        TextView tCustomer, tOrderQty, tWaterType, tAddress;
        Button btnCompelete;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tCustomer = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tCustomer);
            tOrderQty = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tOrderQty);
            tWaterType = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tType);
            tAddress = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tAddress);

            btnCompelete = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnComplete);

            btnCompelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String endpoint = UrlList.main_url + "type=completedeliver&id=" + String.valueOf(itemId);
                    new DeliveryListHelper.CompleteDeliver(itemView.getContext()).execute(endpoint);
                    itemView.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(itemView.getContext(), DeliveryListActivity.class));
                    ((Activity)itemView.getContext()).finish(); `// and here i put this finish`
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public class CompleteDeliver extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        ProgressDialog pd;
        private Context context;

        public CompleteDeliver(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pd = new ProgressDialog(this.context);
            pd.setMessage("Completing...");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            pd.dismiss();
            getResult(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            HttpHelper httpHelper = new HttpHelper(this.context);

            return httpHelper.httpConnect(url[0]);
        }

        private void getResult(String result) {
            Toast.makeText(this.context,
                    result,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you call finish() on an activity, it will close the activity; hence, the closure of your app. So, erase the part that you put finish(), everything should work fine

Comment: yeah, thats the thing i figured out. then is there a way like finishing the activity and reload so that if press the back button of the phone it will not show me again the previous activity?

Comment: OK, you want the MainActivity to reload?

Comment: yeah thats the problem that when I try to remove the finish it works well but when i press the back button of the phone it shows me the same activity that has not been modified.

Comment: Override onRestart() in MainActivity to reload

Comment: Because onRestart() is first called upon coming back to an activity, so do all your list view inside onRestart () again

Comment: So you want to reload the current Activity without going back to the previous one?

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be long, but I suggest you follow a more traditional approach and decouple your Adapter from your Activity (if needed) and your ViewHolder from your Adapter. Even if you never reuse them elsewhere.

What this means is, instead of relying on your ViewHolder to obtain an activity, provide your viewHolder with a callback instead. By the way, `itemView.getContext()` is not necessarily an activity; itemView is a `View` and as such, its context does not necessarily need to be an `Activity`, be careful when assuming that.

Right now you do this:

`Activity->Adapter->ViewHolder->try to cast context to Activity and do things`

What I would do is:

- Activity creates adapter/recyclerview.
- Activity sets a listener in the adapter to be called back when an operation must occur.
- Adapter stores the above listener and every time it creates a new ViewHolder, it passes a **new** listener to each viewHolder.
- The ViewHolder then assigns a `View#onClickListener()` to the button/view/widget(s) you want pressed to trigger actions.
- In this `onClickListener` that the ViewHolder sets, you would call the listener the adapter passed you, with perhaps, the `getAdapterPosition()` of the clicked view.
- The adapter will receive this callback, get the item via the supplied position, and then, call the original listener set by the activity, now with the item at hand.
- The activity will receive this and will do whatever it wants with it.

**WHY GO THIS MORE COMPLICATED ROUTE?**

You should try to decouple things as much as possible; your solution is fighting against the framework by trying to do things where they don’t belong.

You’ve experienced first-hand, why the ViewHolder is **not good** at running background operations; it’s not what it was created/designed for. 
It doesn’t really know (and shouldn’t) what an Activity is to begin with.

The Adapter… well the adapter is just that, it “adapts” data that comes in one format (your list) to be consumed by someone (the RecyclerView). The adapter is the middle-object that talks and supplies your RecyclerView with actual views, and binds the data between your data source (list) and said views (via the ViewHolders), while *efficiently* caching/reusing the views in question; it certainly does not know about Activities and it doesn’t have to.

The activity/fragment, on the other hand, are well versed in the arts of Context(s). They are one themselves or have means to obtain one, flawlessly. (note: view holders can also obtain contexts, as you are well aware via itemView.getContext()) but this context should only be used for “view things”. Namely, fetch resources (strings, colors, drawables), get theme values, etc. Not to replace (or worse, skip) the correct communication between components).

**How complicated does this look in practice?**

I’ll post a simple example and will use mostly pseudo-code where applicable.

(I’ll explain these down below)

In your Adapter, add this:

```
// This is the interface to pass to the adapter
interface OnItemClickedListener {
    void onCompleteDeliver(int itemId);
}
```

In Your ViewHolder, add this:

```
// This is the interface to pass to the ViewHolders. (put this in your ViewHolder, it makes it cleaner).
interface OnClickListener {
     void onCompleteClicked(int position);
}
```

Let’s start modifying your **Activity**.

You inflate your views and then create your adapter and set it to the RecyclerView. That’s the Activity’s job and you’re already doing it.

But now that you have both interfaces defined, modify your activity:

```
recyclerView = findViewById(…);
Adapter adapter = new Adapter(…);

// THIS IS NEW
adapter.setItemClickListener(itemId -> { 
   String endpoint = UrlList.main_url + "type=completedeliver&id=" + String.valueOf(itemId);
   new DeliveryListHelper.CompleteDeliver(getContext()).execute(endpoint);
   // that’s it, when the AsyncTask is done, you can finish or whatever is that you wanted to do. You are in an activity anyway.
});
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

So far, so good we just added that weird setItemClickListener…

Now in your **Adapter**, add the above method like this:

```
void setCompleteListener(OnItemClickedListener listener) {
   this.listener = listener; // save it, you will need it!
}
```

As a nice way to avoid creating N number of these anonymous classes, it’s often a good idea to just have one… so in your adapter add a field:

`private ViewHolder.OnClickListener onClickListener;`

This field’s type is the interface type defined above inside the ViewHolder.

Then in your onCreateViewHolder (still inside the Adapter!) lazy create it:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View getView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_list_delivery, viewGroup, false);
        // Lazy create one, if it’s null, create it, otherwise, use it.
        if (onClickListener == null) {
             // note: the getItem(position) method is part of `ListAdapter`, if you are not using that, then you need to either create a similar way or access your data directly… like myList.get(position) or anywhere you store the object that is bound to this view holder. DataAdapter is very convenient :)
            onClickListener = (position) -> listener. onCompleteClicked(getItem(position));
        }

    // Pass the internal click listener to the viewHolder
    return new ViewHolder(getView, onClickListener); // need to modify VH to accept this… see below…
}
```

Now let’s modify the **ViewHolder**:

Add a constructor to it that takes your OnClickListener:

```
        ViewHolder(View itemView, OnClickListener listener) {
            super(itemView);
            this.listener = listener; //keep it
         …
        }
```

Now what **I WOULD DO**, is instead of creating over 9000 View.OnClickListeners… just have one and reuse it:

(Still inside the ViewHolder)

```
        View.OnClickListener onViewClickedListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                 listener.onCompleteClicked(getAdapterPosition());
            }
        };
```

All this does is when clicked, it will call the listener with the adapter position for itself (remember this is a ViewHolder).

This way, this listener can be reused for any position… so in your ViewHolder constructor for example… below the `this.listener=listener` line

```
btnCompelete = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnComplete);
btnCompelete.setOnClickListener(onViewClickedListener);
```

…

At this point, the picture is more or less complete.

If you go backwards from the ViewHolder:

1. You assign a regular `OnClickListener` to a button (or anything).
2. When this view is clicked, you call your `OnItemClicked`, that was supplied to you at construction, and do `listener.onCompleteClicked(getAdapterPosition());`
3. This is forwarding the event to the `onClickListener` your adapter passed onto these viewHolders. It’s the same instance, because it receives the affected (clicked) position via parameter (so we can reuse it!).
4. The adapter has this `onClickListener` and so when the ViewHolder passes the event here… all the adapter needs to do is fetch the item from its data source… (that is up2you… `getItem(pos)` is a convenience method of a `ListAdapter<T>`, but if you use a *raw* `RecyclerView.Adapter<T>` then you normally keep the list of items to display at hand in the adapter… so query your data source/list/whatever, to obtain a reference to the item that is bound to the clicked view holder.
5. With the item reference obtained, all that is left for the adapter is to pass the event now to the Activity… which is free to do as it pleases.

I hope this long (and maybe plagued with typos) post, helps you understand what the advantages of this kind of method is.

Is it more code?
yes.

Is it harder to debug?
Possibly, but not really.

Is this the **best** way?
Unlikely, but it’ve used these (and many many other similar and not so similar) methods in a bunch of projects and never heard anything bad about this.

Of course, you could be tempted to short-circuit this, and instead of passing a position, pass the actual “ID” of the item, but then again, why? The adapter is responsible for supplying (and maintaining) the relationship between each List “item” and your ViewHolder, let them do their job.

On the other hand, the ViewHolder is short-lived, reusable, and dumb; don’t make it do things it can’t control; imagine your scenario, triggering an Async Task from a ViewHolder that takes 1 minute. The user scrolls in that time… the ViewHolder gets reused… hell breaks.

Anyway, good luck and welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments suggest you want to take out `.finish()` and want to call `.notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter.